# Send data out of visible form only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

I have two divs containing same input fields. When I enter the vales in both the div fields, all the values get submitted. what I want is, only the value of selected div (using radio button) should pass. Any help will be appreciated :-)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  console.log('called');

  $('input[type=radio][name=cancel_policy]').change(function() {
    if (this.value == '0') {
      $("#fixedPolicyDiv").css("display", "block");
      $("#percentagePolicyDiv").css("display", "none");
      $("#percentagePolicyDiv").get(0).reset();

    } else if (this.value == '1') {
      $("#fixedPolicyDiv").css("display", "none");
      $("#fixedPolicyDiv").get(0).reset();
      $("#percentagePolicyDiv").css("display", "block");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="custom-control custom-control-primary custom-radio">
  <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="cancel_policy" value="0"> <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
  <span class="custom-control-label">Fixed price</span> 
</label>

<label class="custom-control custom-control-primary custom-radio">
  <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="cancel_policy" value="1"> <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
  <span class="custom-control-label">Percentage wise</span> 
</label>

<div id="fixedPolicyDiv" style="display:none;">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-11 col-lg-offset-1">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table" id='cancel_tbl'>
          <tr>
            <td width='30%'>Days</td>
            <td width='30%'>Amount</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="number" name="cancel_policy_days[]" class="form-control" placeholder="days" value="<?= set_value('cancel_policy_days[]') ?>" required="required" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="number" name="cancel_policy_amount[]" class="form-control" placeholder="cancellation amount" value="<?= set_value('cancel_policy_amount[]') ?>" required="required" />
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="6" align="center">
              <input type="button" value="Add More" id="cancel_addmorebtn1" class="btn btn-outline-info">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="percentagePolicyDiv" style="display:none;">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-11 col-lg-offset-1">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table" id='cancel_tb2'>
          <tr>
            <td width='30%'>Days</td>
            <td width='30%'>Percentage</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="number" name="cancel_policy_days[]" class="form-control" placeholder="days" value="<?= set_value('cancel_policy_days[]') ?>" required="required" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="number" name="cancel_policy_amount[]" class="form-control" placeholder="cancellation percentage" value="<?= set_value('cancel_policy_amount[]') ?>" required="required" />
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="6" align="center">
              <input type="button" value="Add More" id="cancel_addmorebtn2" class="btn btn-outline-info">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all you should provide us with your radio-elements, then you can make two forms and select in serialization procedure one of them. You can always use `:visible` selector to get visible elements only (it may be the same `<form>`-element.

Comment: `<label class="custom-control custom-control-primary custom-radio">
                           <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="cancel_policy" value="0">
                           <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                           <span class="custom-control-label">Fixed price</span>
                         </label>`

Comment: `<label class="custom-control custom-control-primary custom-radio">
                           <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="cancel_policy" value="1">
                           <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                           <span class="custom-control-label">Percentage wise</span>
                         </label>`

Comment: Its in same form @Daniel

Comment: It's not a form ever. Form is `<form>` tag first.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the disabled property to the inputs you do not want to sent.
for exemple :

```
$("#percentagePolicyDiv").find('input').prop('disabled');
```

Comment: Or extend elector with `:visible` attribute also

Comment: @Daniel can you give an example please?

Comment: Check my answer above. I will expand my code example if you need it.

Comment: @HamzaChoudary I'm glad to be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

If `reset()` is not only JS method you accept, we can make it with setting value of input fields such way:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  console.log('called');

  $('input[type=radio][name=cancel_policy]').change(function() {
    if (this.value == '0') {
      $("#percentagePolicyDiv").find('input').val('');

      $("#fixedPolicyDiv").css("display", "block");
      $("#percentagePolicyDiv").css("display", "none");

    } else if (this.value == '1') {

      $("#fixedPolicyDiv").find('input').val('');

      $("#fixedPolicyDiv").css("display", "none");
      $("#percentagePolicyDiv").css("display", "block");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="custom-control custom-control-primary custom-radio">
  <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="cancel_policy" value="0"> <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
  <span class="custom-control-label">Fixed price</span> 
</label>

<label class="custom-control custom-control-primary custom-radio">
  <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="cancel_policy" value="1"> <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
  <span class="custom-control-label">Percentage wise</span> 
</label>

<div id="fixedPolicyDiv" style="display:none;">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-11 col-lg-offset-1">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table" id='cancel_tbl'>
          <tr>
            <td width='30%'>Days</td>
            <td width='30%'>Amount</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="number" name="cancel_policy_days[]" class="form-control" placeholder="days" value="<?= set_value('cancel_policy_days[]') ?>" required="required" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="number" name="cancel_policy_amount[]" class="form-control" placeholder="cancellation amount" value="<?= set_value('cancel_policy_amount[]') ?>" required="required" />
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="6" align="center">
              <input type="button" value="Add More" id="cancel_addmorebtn1" class="btn btn-outline-info">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="percentagePolicyDiv" style="display:none;">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-11 col-lg-offset-1">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table" id='cancel_tb2'>
          <tr>
            <td width='30%'>Days</td>
            <td width='30%'>Percentage</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="number" name="cancel_policy_days[]" class="form-control" placeholder="days" value="<?= set_value('cancel_policy_days[]') ?>" required="required" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="number" name="cancel_policy_amount[]" class="form-control" placeholder="cancellation percentage" value="<?= set_value('cancel_policy_amount[]') ?>" required="required" />
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="6" align="center">
              <input type="button" value="Add More" id="cancel_addmorebtn2" class="btn btn-outline-info">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise you should implement desired ID to `<form>` elements.

formObject.reset() is JS method of FORM-object